# Ionic button ng-click

Tags: angularjs, button, ionic-framework, angular-ui-router

I do have a different button on my first page.I just want to move to respective page on clicking to each button.However this is not working.I am new to ionic. Plz help.

Here is my controller.js

```
`angular.module('starter.controllers', [])

.controller('TutorialsCtrl', function($scope) {})


  .controller('AndroidCtrl', function($scope,$state) {
    $scope.create = function () {
      $state.go('templates/android');
    };
  });`
```

This is my app.js

```
 .config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

  $stateProvider

    .state('tab', {
    url: '/tab',
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: 'templates/tabs.html'
  })

  // Each tab has its own nav history stack:

  .state('tab.tutorials', {
    url: '/tutorials',
    views: {
      'tab-tutorials': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/tutorials.html',
        controller: 'TutorialsCtrl'
      }
    }
  })
    .state('tab.android',{
      url:'/tutorials/:tutorialId',
      views:{
        'tab-tutorials':{
          templateUrl:'templates/android.html',
          controller:'AndroidCtrl'
        }

      }
    })

  });

  // if none of the above states are matched, use this as the fallback
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/tab/tutorials');

});
```

here is my tutorials.html page

```
   <ion-view view-title="Tutorials">
  <ion-content class="padding">
    <div class="background">
      <button class="button button-outline button-positive myandroid" ng-click="create()">
        <i class="icon ion-social-android home"></i>
        <p>Android</p>
      </button>
    </div>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

I want to navigate from tutorials.html to android.html.I do have a blank android.html page at this instant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `button` use `a`(anchor) as you wanted to change the state(route) of your application. And on each anchor you could use `ui-sref` directive with respective `stateName`, so that will create create a required `href` tag over there.

**Markup**

```
<ion-view view-title="Tutorials">
  <ion-content class="padding">
    <div class="background">
      <a class="button button-outline button-positive myandroid" ui-sref="tab.tutorials">
        <i class="icon ion-social-android home"></i>
        <p>Android</p>
      </button>
    </div>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Comment: Thank you so much pankaj bro.You made a quit easy soln

Comment: @Ramesh glad to know that. Thanks

Comment: I did't do it.I dn't know how it happened brother.Any way i will definitely mark it as right.Thanks for letting me know

Answer (score 0):

With `$state.go()` you can go to a state, not to a template as you did.

```
 $scope.create = function () {
     $state.go('tab.android');
 };
```